# Chrome + JSFiddle OPTION element bug

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jsfiddle

This really has me scratching my head.

The OPTION text is cleared using this code in a Snippet:

```js
document.querySelector('option').textContent = '';
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Ipso</option>
</select>
```

It also works in a [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxdykJ), plus it works on my website.

However, in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/so4L45s5/3/) it fails – *but only in Chrome*.

If I set `textContent` to anything *prior* to clearing it, [**it then works**](https://jsfiddle.net/so4L45s5/4/).

This issue [**doesn't seem to occur**](https://jsfiddle.net/so4L45s5/2/) with any other type of element.

If I use `innerText` or `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`, I get the same behavior – but again, only in Chrome.  jQuery's **text()** method also gives the same behavior.

Is this a Chrome bug or a JSFiddle bug?

Comment: Because your fiddle's setting are incorrect and you're loading the script in the wrong place. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/so4L45s5/5/. Change the load type option.

Comment: Thanks, @j08691, that makes some sense, but why would it make a difference only if the `textContent` is an empty string?  See https://jsfiddle.net/so4L45s5/7/.  Also, why is the OPTION element affected only?

Comment: When I click "run" on your JSFiddle link, in Chrome, then it works fine. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin.  JSFiddle should auto-run, and you'll see that my second fiddle ("it then works") does auto-run properly.  This must have to do with the proprietary nature of how different browsers implement the SELECT element.

Comment: Also note that the problem occurs only when you set `textContent` to an empty string.  It doesn't occur if you set it to anything else:  https://jsfiddle.net/so4L45s5/16/  That's just bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for the bug, but try setting the load type (click the cog in the top right corner of the JavaScript frame) and select `no wrap - in <body>`.

[image]

It works on the Chrome browser on my phone (whilst your fiddle didn't), and could possibly explain what's gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue, but it remains a mystery why it occurs in the first place.  (Sorry, don't know why this was downvoted.)

Comment: @RickHitchcock No need to apologise :). And, yes, I have idea either